# R, sparklyr - cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, apache-spark

I have a problem with copying my data frame into local Spark cluster. I try to follow steps on this site: https://spark.rstudio.com/
I connected to my cluster like this:

```
> library(sparklyr)
> sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

Then I tested copying object into cluster:

```
> library(dplyr)
> iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)
```

And it worked fine. I see this object in IDE for Sparc.

Then I tried to do this same thing with my data frame:

```
> my_df_tbl <- copy_to(sc, my_df)
```

There was this error:

> Error in UseMethod("invoke") : 
>     no applicable method for 'invoke' applied to an object of class "character"

When I tried to do this:

```
> copy_to(sc, my_df)
```

I got this error:

> Error in as.vector(x, "character") :    cannot coerce type
>   'environment' to vector of type 'character'

I checked both objects to see if both are of this same type:\

```
> class(iris)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(my_df)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Do you have any idea why it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (or the bug). I do not know why I didn't get this errors before but after opening RStudio and my project for a second time I tried to do this:

```
library(sparklyr)
```

And I got error that I do not have packages shiny and rlang. I installed them:

```
> install.packages("shiny")
> install.packages("rlang")
```

Then I again tried to copy my data frame and it worked without problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to use an earlier version of sparklyr. I changed the version from 0.7.0 to 0.5.6.